# ui-grid grid menu: how to change the text of the default values of show/hide column

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have enabled the grid menu using

```
gridOptions.enableGridMenu = true
```

I am getting the grid menu with an option to show/hide individual columns. I would like to customize the "columns" text that appears here. I am not using the i18 service of Angular as I have my own resources. How can I change that text?

Please refer to this

[image]

Also, can I hide the "Clear all filters" menu item?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it with removeFromGridMenu, but it fails because the grid.gridMenuScope.registeredMenuItems contains "Export all data as csv", "Export visible data as csv", etc. but not "Clear all filters". It appears that it is hard-coded to be added by getMenuItems.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already resolved your issue but, AFAIK there is no way to change the default text of the default menu items without using i18nService. Apart from suppressing all the defaults and adding your custom menu items that is.

You could try to override the default text using your customs like this [How to change the default text of UI-Grid menu option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803718/how-to-change-the-default-text-of-ui-grid-menu-option).

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of this tutorial for Grid Menu Section
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/121_grid_menu in the new UI grid

Check this function:

$interval( function() 
{

gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{ title: 'Dynamic item', order: 100}]);

gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{ title: 'New item', order: 600}]);
      }, 0, 1);

.....

**gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{ title: 'New item', order: 600}]);
      }, 0, 1);**

addToGridMenu(grid, items)

add items to the grid menu. Used by features to add their menu items if they are enabled, can also be used by end users to add menu items. This method has the advantage of allowing remove again, which can simplify management of which items are included in the menu when. (Noting that in most cases the shown and active functions provide a better way to handle visibility of menu items)

Parameters
Param   Type    Details
grid
Grid
the grid on which we are acting

items
array
menu items in the format as described in the tutorial, with the added note that if you want to use remove you must also specify an id field, which is provided when you want to remove an item. The id should be unique.